# How to export a reference to a #begin_src block to LaTeX

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

I'm exporting an ORG file to LaTeX with `org-latex-listings` set to `t`. The file contains some source listings, and I want to insert some references to them.

In the generated TEX file, the reference names included in `\ref` seems to be translated by org-mode, but the `label` option of `\lstset` is keept as is. This way, `pdflatex` can't find the correct reference and gives the message `LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.`

Here is an example of a MWE:

```
#+latex_header: \usepackage{listings}
First simple java program in listing [[thesourcelisting]]
#+name: thesourcelisting
#+caption: Simple java program
#+BEGIN_SRC java
public static void main(String[] args){
  System.exit(0);
}
#+END_SRC
```

When exported as a LaTeX file  (`C-c` `C-e` `l` `t`), I got

```
% Created 2016-10-18 mar 14:50
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}

\author{alvaro}
\date{\today}
\title{}
\hypersetup{
 pdfauthor={alvaro},
 pdftitle={},
 pdfkeywords={},
 pdfsubject={},
 pdfcreator={Emacs 25.1.2 (Org mode 8.3.6)}, 
 pdflang={English}}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

First simple java program in listing \ref{orgsrcblock1}
\lstset{language=java,label=thesourcelisting,caption={Simple java program},captionpos=b,numbers=none}
\begin{lstlisting}
public static void main(String[] args){
  System.exit(0);
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

The original name `thesourcelisting` is translated to `orgsrcblock1` in the  `\ref` command, but not in the `\lstset` command.

I'm using GNU Emacs 25.1.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `org-latex-prefer-user-labels` to `t`.

The doc string of the variable says in part (do `C-h v org-latex-prefer-user-labels RET` to get the whole thing):

> Use user-provided labels instead of internal ones when non-nil.
>
> When this variable is non-nil, Org will use the value of
>   CUSTOM_ID property, NAME keyword or Org target as the key for the
>   \label commands generated.
>
> By default, Org generates its own internal labels during LaTeX
>   export.  This process ensures that the \label keys are unique
>   and valid, but it means the keys are not available in advance of
>   the export process.